# What is the difference between the 2 ways of calling jquery functions?

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between the calling of jquery functions using `on` and after `find` using `on`

```
<div class="outer">
    <span>One</span>
    <div class="inner"><button id="button">button 1</button></div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <span>Two</span>
    <div class="inner"><button id="button">button 2</button></div>
</div>
```

The jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div.outer').on('click',".inner #button",function(event){
        console.log(this);//this works
    });
    $('div.outer').find(".inner #button").on("click",function(event){
        console.log(this);//this works
    });
    $('div.outer').find(".outer span").on('click',function(event){
        console.log(this);//this not works
    });
});
```

Here it is a simple example I am creating a jquery plugin which has multiple instances so each button clicked twice. I used `jquery.off` before bind each function, but it not works.

Comment: *Ids must be unique!* :)

Comment: ...and `.outer span` is not inside `div.outer`, only `span` is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is a dynamic event handler, it binds the event to `div.outer`, a parent of `#button`, but filters based on the `#button` selector, that way it works even if the element is not present at the time the event is bound, i.e. dynamically insterted elements.

The two last ones are regular event handlers, and `find()` just finds an element within another element, so in the middle one it searches for `#button` within `.inner` within `.outer`, and attaches a regular event handler to `#button`.

As ID's are unique, it's really uneccssary to use find that way, as just `$('#button').on()` should be enough.

In the last one the click is bound to the span, and not the button, so any click on the button  will not fire the event, but clicking on the span will.

**EDIT:**

Your selector searches for `.outer` inside `.outer`, that's why it's not working, you should be searching for just a span inside .outer, so this:

```
$('div.outer').find(".outer span")
```

should be this:

```
$('div.outer').find("span")
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/F7uUF/1/)

Comment: here the event on span is not working whereas the button works, I tested here http://jsfiddle.net/F7uUF/

Comment: @RohanKumar - seems like a mixup with the selector, edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**IDs must be unique.**

Not sure what are you trying to do, but according to HTML structure

```
$('div.outer').find(".outer span").length === 0; //true
```

Answer (score 0):

using on() you should be able to attach an event listener to any element and specify that it can be triggered by another (inside that element);

on this case the event listener will be on the element with id 'button'

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    console.log('if you dynamically remove #button from the page the event will be lost');
})
```

on this case this the event listener will be on the element body:

```
$('body').on('click', '#button', function(){
    console.log('if you dynamically remove #button from the page the event will not be lost');
})
```

Now, regarding using find(), I prefer using css selectors, try something like this:

```
$('div.outer span').on('click', function(event){
    console.log('this works');
    console.log(event.currentTarget); //the element you have clicked on
});
```